# Draw bitmaps on top of the Navigation bar in Android

Tags: android, overlay, navigationbar, viewgroup

In my application, I need to draw a bitmap on top of all the apps running. I created a view which is invisible and overlays on top of all the apps. with this overlay view I can draw bitmaps at the given position , But I am unable to draw the bitmap on top of the Navigation Bar.I used the following layout parameters.

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR 
    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
```

I need help in solving this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the issue myself , to draw on top of navigation bar at the bottom of the android , I have to give an offset in the Y position while defining the windowManager.Layout params as below.

```
w = new android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams(-1, -1,0,-navigationBarHeight(),    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR 
    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, Pixel.Translucent);
    f.addView(v, w);
```

note: This only works when the navigation bar is translucent

Comment: Hi, @sash! I want to ask you about where I should place this code and what type of f?

Comment: Does this work for you all the time?
It seems that it only works when the Navigation bar is semi transparent (on launcher and some of google apps) but if it's completely opaque, it still draw behind it

Comment: @Vlad, it does not work for me always either (it works most of the time -- I found only a couple of apps (k-9 among them) It probably has something to do with min supported version) . It is not an opaque vs. translucent differentiation though. Not sure what it is...

Comment: @miha You are right.. it only works when the background of the navigation bar is transparent

Comment: @Vlad, I was just playing around - in one custom application, it made a difference when I used target SDK. If target SDK was set to 21 or above, you could draw over navbar, otherwise not. On another app (this made no difference). Flaky...

Comment: seems from 5.0 on this is not possible anymore: http://room-15.github.io/blog/2015/03/17/overlaying-the-system-navigation-bar/

Comment: @Vlad Did you ever find a way to get it working in all apps? I can't get mine to draw over the navbar in certain apps like Chrome and Tinder profile view mode only! It simply draws under the navbar.

Comment: @Flyview Nope. Sometimes the navbar is transparent so it seems you're drawing above it, but you don't actually ever draw above the navbar. This is by design