# Overlay over navigation bar in Android 4

Tags: android, navigation, overlay

I am struggling with this despite going through some samples...

I want to overlay over the android navigation bar - I have tried the following code...

```
s_translucentParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                ,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

But of course, that fills a window which does not cover the navigation bar...  after doing some reading, I tried the following (from [Draw bitmaps on top of the Navigation bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380167/draw-bitmaps-on-top-of-the-navigation-bar-in-android)) ...

```
w = new android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams(-1, -1,0,-navigationBarHeight(),    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR 
|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, Pixel.Translucent);
f.addView(v, w);
```

But this does not overlay for me despite me altering the window size ... it just doesn't overlap the navigation bar :(

I want to make something like the following...

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor&hl=en_GB

This does not display above the navigation bar, but below it (which is fine for my needs)

Can anyone help me?  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see on screenshots at your Play Market link is Android KitKat's (API 19) Translucent Decor.

> You can now make the system bars partially translucent with new
>   themes, `Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor` and
>   `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor`. By enabling translucent
>   system bars, your layout will fill the area behind the system bars, so
>   you must also enable `fitsSystemWindows` for the portion of your layout
>   that should not be covered by the system bars.
>
> If you're creating a custom theme, set one of these themes as the
>   parent theme or include the `windowTranslucentNavigation` and
>   `windowTranslucentStatus` style properties in your theme.

Your translucent Activity should be declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` like:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.app.TranslucentActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor" />
```

Other way you might want to go is just hiding Navigation Bar with API 14+:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Or you might want to use Immersive Full-screen Mode with API 19:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);}
}
```

Take a look at [Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) and [Hiding the Navigation Bar](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html) for more detailed information.

Comment: This is a perfect reply and covers many ways to sort the problem depending on version; thanks a lot for this!!